# How to pass kinit info in R script

Tags: r, hadoop, hive, rstudio

I'm trying to establish a hive jdbc connection in through R. I'm not using hiveR package, just simple R script and connecting to kerberized hadoop cluster.
I've added kinit as "system("kinit hive@XX.com")", it is asking for password and it accept it successfully. But it fails after few minute with "GSS initiate failed". Is there a way we can specify in R script to read from cache or how to deal with this. Also I've tried kinit first then launch R shell, it doesn't pick kinit. Thanks in advance.

Comment: R does not care about Kerberos, it's the Hive JDBC driver that does the messy authentication stuff. And Kerberos is an occult science, especially with Hadoop, cf. https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/secrets.html